# «À présent que les voix se sont tues» : Quel est le verbe?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, conjugaison

Je doute sérieusement que le verbe soit "tuer". D'autre part, c'est le seul verbe que je trouve au dictionnaire avec cette forme verbale. J'ai dû me tromper quelque part...  Est-ce qu'il y en a un autre qui peut être adéquat à la situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Le verbe dans cette phrase est *taire* (sous sa forme pronominale).

Le participe passé est différent de celui du verbe *tuer* :

> Elles se sont tues (verbe *taire*)
>
> Elles se sont tuées (verbe *tuer*)